# Database error Qt

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, qt4, qt-creator

I have built a Qt application (based on Qt 4.7.4 and QtCreator 2.4.1) and trying to deploy it. When I run the application.exe from the release folder then everything works fine. I have a sqlite3 database included. When I try to extract the data from it through the application it works fine.

And also when I copy the contents on to another computer the application runs just fine.
But, when I try to extract the data from it through the application then in the other computer  I get an error message box(it's a custom error).
I cross checked whether the database is open or not. Its open but still I am not able to extract any data from the database.

I would like to know how do I solve this problem of connecting to the database?

Comment: Have you copied the `sqlite3` plugin over?

Comment: I copied the sqlite3.dll. It doesn't work.

Comment: Add the directory structure/contents (of special interest arethe main .exe, the Qt DLLs and the plugins) and the possibly also the code where it fails. If open() succeeds but you get no data, it might be that you’re accidentally creating a new empty database on disk (the sqlite plugin will do that if you pass a non-existing filename in an existing and writable directory)

Comment: I copied the sqilte3.dll into a plugins folder and placed it in the application folder and it worked.